# Determine which CSS Framework is used with Selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium, frameworks

I am writing a Programm which crawls through various Webpages and does some tests using Selenium.
Now I want to find out which CSS Frameworks are used on these Websites to get some statistics.
Right now I just check with the FireFox Webdriver if on there are .css Files linked in the page which have the name of a specific Framework:
 `Iterator<WebElement> divWebElementIteratorCSS = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//link[@rel='stylesheet']")).iterator();`

and then I check if the name of the found .css Files contains the name of one of the CSS Frameworks I would like to check:

```
if ( src.contains( frameWorkName ) && cssFrameWorks.get( frameWorkName ) == false ) {
    result.addAttribute("Framework", "STRING", frameWorkName);
    result.setPercent( 100 );
    result.setSuccessful( true );
    cssFrameWorks.put( frameWorkName, true );
}
```

The Hashmap frameWorkName contains all the names of the Frameworks I am interested in.

Now my problem: If the administrator of the site renamed the .css file of the framework, my test does not work! Is there a safe way to check this, which works even if the .css has a different name?

Comment: what is a "CSS framework"? Do you have an example?

Comment: Something like Bootstrap, Foundation or YAML!

Comment: Why do you need to know this information? What use does it have to you, whether they used YAML or something else?

Comment: My boss wants to have a statistic, which frameworks are used for responsive design support by our partners (there are way to many to do it manually or just ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @AaronDigulla's answer is pretty clear.

An alternative that I can think of though, is when you iterate through those, do a GET on that css file, then do a quick scan through the documentation at the beginning.  For example, a CSS file might contain...

```
/*  CSS Framework vX.X
 *  Author: Some Author
 *  License:
 *    Some ridiculously long license
 */
```

This would alleviate your file name changes issue.

Answer (score 2):

I know no reliable way to determine which CSS (or JavaScript) frameworks are being used in a web site.

If you're lucky, then the admins will use a global URL (like the [CDN links provided by jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)).

When people start to rename files, you can try to download the CSS file and fingerprint it (create a checksum).

That will fail, of course, when people change those files. This can happen automatically; [wro4j](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/) is a framework that will compile all JavaScript and CSS resources into one big file each automatically.

I'm also a bit worried why you would need this information. Instead of trying to figure out which framework is being used (and which version) look for the actual CSS styles that are being applied which might influence your tests.